# How to trace error in google app engine?

Tags: android, google-app-engine

I have following setup:

1. Custom API on Android studio.
2. That API makes a call to google cloud sql to retrieve manipulate data.

Query works perfectly on dev server. But when I deploy it to google app engine query does not work. Nothing get updated in table. I can trace error on dev server to fix local bugs. Is there any way to check/trace error google app engine may be in its console?

Comment: Yes, you should look at the logs in the console.  Have you remembered to add the app to the set of ones enabled on that google cloud sql answer?

Comment: If you mean giving permission to app for using a sql instance, then yes I did. Please can you tell where is option to see logs in console?

Comment: https://console.developers.google.com/project , pick project, Monitoring from the left-hand navbar, Logs under it -- now the main pane shows all queries that made log entries, click the triangle next to any of them to open the list of log lines written for that query.